# CoreLocation update 10Hz - using interpolation

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, interpolation, core-location

I was thinking about interpolating speed of location from Core Location.
If person is driving (accelerating) and I want to measure how fast accelerated from 100kmh to 200kmh, location update of 1Hz is not precise for me because I can get 199.9kmh update and next one to be 204kmh.
If I save all updates to database and iterate them later, it's doable to create interpolated location updated between them.
Is there any way to interpolate locations while they are updating? Some ideas?

Comment: If you want accleration data, wouldn't you be better off with Core Motion?

Answer (score 1):

You can store all speed data, and then use a correlation method to make a continual speed-time function `f(t)`, which you can then solve `f(t)=200` for t.

As the comment suggested, you can combine speed data and acceleration data with a Kalman filter to generate a better `f(t)`. Refer to [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8860/kalman-filter-for-position-and-velocity-introducing-speed-estimates)

Comment: Thx, I will take a look at reference.